# Segmentation faults every time I try to take command line input

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I've been working on a program that takes one string as command line input and outputs whether the string made up of the odd numbered characters is a palindrome, but every time I try to run it I get a segmentation fault. I've been up all night and can't figure it out.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    if (argc == 1) {
        printf("Give a string please\n");
        return 0;
    }

    //char *ptr1;
    //ptr1 = malloc(sizeof(char)*100);
    //int memSize = strlen(argv[1]);
    //leftovers from previous attempts I may get back to
    char *str1 = argv[1];

    if (isPalindrome(*str1))
        printf("it is a palindrome");
    else
        printf("not a palindrome");
} 

int isPalindrome(char str[])
{
    char oddStr[sizeof(char)*50];
    int j = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < strlen(*str); i++) {
        if(i%2 == 1) {
            oddStr[j] = str[i];
            j++;
        }
    }


    int i = 0;
    int k = strlen(&oddStr) - 1;

    while (k > i) {
        if (oddStr[i++] != oddStr[k--])
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Every time I run it I get this error:

> Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Does anyone know what might be causing it?

Comment: Change `if(isPalindrome(*str1))` to `if(isPalindrome(str1))` — you need to pass a pointer to this function, not a char. Didn't your compiler say anything? Try compiling with warnings enabled next time.

Comment: Check your call to isPalindrome.

Comment: `strlen(*str)`  Doesn't your compiler shout at you?  `*str` is a single character and does not have a length.

Comment: You forgot to NUL-terminate `oddStr`. Add `oddStr[j] = '\0';` after the for loop.

Comment: It's so strange that we keep getting a flood of questions like this suddenly. This isn't valid C. What kind of crapiler let it through?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the issues:-

1.`strlen` takes a character array as an input (a `char *`  pointer)

2. The size of the array `oddStr` must be known at compile time if it is
   used on stack. Otherwise it should be created on heap via
   `malloc`.

Please find the correct working code below:-

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if (argc == 1)
    {
      printf ("Give a string please\n");
      return 0;
    }

  char *str1 = argv[1];

  if (isPalindrome (str1))
    printf ("it is a palindrome");
  else
    printf ("not a palindrome");
}

int isPalindrome (char str[])
{

  //char oddStr[sizeof (char) * 50];
  char * oddStr = (char *)malloc(sizeof (char) * 50);

  int j = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++)
    {
      if (i % 2 == 1)
    {
      oddStr[j] = str[i];
      j++;
    }
    }


  int i = 0;
  int k = strlen (oddStr) - 1;

  while (k > i)
    {
      if (oddStr[i++] != oddStr[k--])
    {
      return 0;
    }
    }
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: You forgot about one issue, when calling `strlen(oddStr)` *oddStr* should be ended with null-terminated character, so there are 2 solutions: [1] add `oddStr[j] = 0` after for loop, or [2] call `calloc` instead of `malloc`.

Comment: Thank you, this was a huge help. I don't know if I would have caught that second issue. Thanks again!!

Answer (score 1):

### Your problem

```
if (isPalindrome(*str1))
```

Since `str` is a type `char *`, here, you are passing a character to your `isPalindrome()` function, not a string!

### Solution

Do not dereference your pointer, simply pass it like this:

```
if (isPalindrome(str1))
```

Also, **don't forget to enable your compiler's warnings**. That mistake can be detected by your compiler, you would avoid wasting time debugging your code to find the error.

With `gcc` and `clang`, use the flags `-Wall` and `-Wextra`.

Comment: Than you so much! I actually do have them enabled, but I'm very new to programming (coming from a bit of java in eclipse to working on c in bash has been a pretty rough transition) so I don't exactly understand what all the error messages mean, but I'll make sure to look them all up next time before asking. Thanks again, it helped a ton!

Answer (score 0):

`*str1` is a char, not an array of char. So try this

```
isPalindrome(str1)
```

Comment: Make sure you compile your programs with `-Wall -Wextra` and strive for no warnings.